# filter out content between two files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, filter

I have two files

#### conditions.txt

```
abcd
efgh
```

#### logs.txt

```
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

I am expecting output to be:

```
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

Actual output:

```
efgh
ijkl
ijkl
mnop
mnop
qrst
qrst
```

Here's the code I had worked till now

```
func(){
while read condition
do
if [[ $line = $condition ]] ; then
:
else
echo "$line";
done < condition.txt
}

while read line
do
func $line
done < log.txt
```

Comment: Your code prints the tested line each time it doesn't match one of the lines in the `condition.txt` file.  If you added two more lines (say `pqrst` and `wxyz`) to `condition.txt`, you'd see 4 occurrences of each line except `abcd` (you'd see 3 occurrences of that).  You should only print the line when it doesn't match any of the lines in `condition.txt`.  But the suggestions to use `fgrep` (or `grep -F`) in the answers are much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using grep:

```
$ grep -v -f conditions.txt logs.txt
```

From the man page for GNU grep:

```
-v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

-f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -e (--regexp)  option,  search  for  all  patterns
          given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: And you could add `-x` if it is exact (full line) matches that are required.  With the example words, it isn't really clear.

Comment: Thanks for this, i am expecting the same answer but i want to compare a part of the $line (only $8 where it has $1 to $8) to $command. Is there a way?

Comment: @user1934439 - this comment doesn't seem to match the sample input you've provided in your question. If you can provide a more complete set of sample input, it may be easier to figure out what you want. THIS answer covers everything that's currently in your question, and explains how it works as an added bonus.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment @user1934439, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel like re-inventing wheels ...

```
grep -vf conditions.txt logs.txt 
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i am expecting the same answer but i want to compare a part of the $line (it has $1 to $8) to $command. Is there a way?

Comment: @user1934439 - you may want to modify your question/example code for this ... that input doesn't match what you posted at all.